# Get the file size - PHP

Tags: php

```
$retornoTotal;
function getRemoteFilesize($link, $formatSize = true)
{
    //echo "link que veio", $link;
    $head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($link, 1));
    // content-length of download (in bytes), read from Content-Length: field
    $clen = isset($head['content-length']) ? $head['content-length'] : 0;
    // cannot retrieve file size, return "-1"
    if (!$clen) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (!$formatSize) {
        return $clen; // return size in bytes
    }
    $size = $clen;
    switch ($clen) {
        case $clen < 1024:
            $size = $clen .' B'; break;
        case $clen < 1048576:
            $size = round($clen / 1024, 2) .' KiB'; break;
        case $clen < 1073741824:
            $size = round($clen / 1048576, 2) . ' MiB'; break;
        case $clen < 1099511627776:
            $size = round($clen / 1073741824, 2) . ' GiB'; break;
    }
    return $size; // return formatted size
}
$links = array();
$lines = file("D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\scripts\\tamanho\\tamanho_por_links\\lista.txt");
foreach($lines as $line){
    $links[] = $line;
}
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($links); $i++) {
    $retornoTotal = getRemoteFilesize($links[$i]);
}
echo "Tamanho Total: ", $retornoTotal;
```

I'm doing this script to check the size of a file on an external server (using a url list) and make a sum of the size of each file, returning the total size.
The problem is that this is only adding the size of the first file, does anyone know where I'm going wrong?
Example: If the first file is 1MB, the rest will be the same size. Consequently, it adds 1MB to the total number of links in the list.txt file.

My list.txt file:

```
https://www.caco.ic.unicamp.br/manjaro/stable/core/x86_64/acl-2.2.53-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst
https://www.caco.ic.unicamp.br/manjaro/stable/core/x86_64/amd-ucode-20201023.r1747.dae4b4c-1-any.pkg.tar.zst
https://www.caco.ic.unicamp.br/manjaro/stable/core/x86_64/b43-fwcutter-019-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

Comment: You are not summing them you are overwriting `$retornoTotal` each time through the loop.

Comment: use `$retornoTotal +=...`

Comment: Voting to close as typo

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: As I committed in the colleague's answer below, even adding "+ =" or using array_sum () in the same way it ends up adding only the first value that is obtained, if the first value is 2 and there are 4 items in the list it will add 2 + 2 + 2 + 2, even if the sizes are different.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `$retornoTotal` each time, you need to sum them.  Also, you have some redundant code and a `foreach` is simpler:

```
$links = file("D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\scripts\\tamanho\\tamanho_por_links\\lista.txt");
$retornoTotal = 0;

foreach($links as $link) {
    $retornoTotal += getRemoteFilesize($link);
}
echo "Tamanho Total: ", $retornoTotal;
```

Or if you want an array of the different sizes, then sum them after:

```
$links = file("D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\scripts\\tamanho\\tamanho_por_links\\lista.txt");

foreach($links as $link) {
    $retorno[] = getRemoteFilesize($link);
}
$retornoTotal = array_sum($retorno);
echo "Tamanho Total: ", $retornoTotal;
```

Comment: It didn't work, he keeps sending the same size for all files and adding them. Example: Let's say we have 4 lines in the file and the first file was 6892, all other files will be that size, and then 6892 + 6892 + 6892 + 6892 will be done, this is not right.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

```
foreach($links as $link) {
    $tamanho = $tamanho + remote_size(rtrim($link));
}
echo 'Bytes: ', $tamanho, '<br>';
```

Changing only within the foreach and resolved for me, the rest was unnecessary code. Thank you all.